# How to resolve the highlight section in Tailwind CSS

Tags: javascript, html, tailwind-css, alpine.js

If I click the "View Log" and "Add Note" button, The popup will open. If Popup is open means, there is 2 marked section is highlighted. but at the same time If I click other button for popup it was working fine. Please check the screenshot for highlighted section.

[image].

Here I attach the code:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@2.8.2/dist/alpine.min.js" defer></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div class="relative">
            <div class="w-full overflow-x-scroll ">
                <table class="divide-y divide-gray-200 table-auto">
                    <thead
                        class="text-xs font-medium tracking-wider text-left text-white uppercase bg-blue-600 whitespace-nowrap">
                        <tr class="py-4 divide-x">
                            <th scope="col" class="sticky left-0 z-10 p-4 bg-blue-600">
                                Name</th>
                            <th scope="col" class="p-4">
                                In Time</th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody
                        class="text-sm bg-white divide-y divide-gray-200 whitespace-nowrap">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="sticky left-0 w-full p-4 bg-white whitespace-nowrap">
                                <div class="flex items-center gap-2 w-max">
                                    <img class="w-8 h-8 rounded-full"
                                        src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/11.jpg"
                                        alt="">
                                        <div>
                                            <a href="" class="font-medium text-blue-600">John
                                                Doe</a>
                                            <p class="text-xs text-gray-600">NA_1110</p>
                                        </div>

                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <div class="flex items-center gap-4">
                                        <div x-data="{ 'showModal': false }" @keydown.escape="showModal = false">
                                            <button @click="showModal = true" class="text-sm text-blue-600">View Logs
                                            </button>

                                            <div class="fixed inset-0 z-30 flex items-center justify-center overflow-auto bg-black bg-opacity-50" x-show="showModal" style="display: none;">
                                                <!-- Modal inner -->
                                                <div class="w-11/12 px-6 py-4 mx-auto text-left bg-white rounded shadow-lg md:max-w-md" @click.away="showModal = false" x-transition:enter="motion-safe:ease-out duration-300" x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 scale-90" x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 scale-100">
                                                    <!-- Title / Close-->
                                                    <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                                                        <p class="font-bold text-gray-900">
                                                            Attendance Log
                                                        </p>
                                                        <span @click="showModal = false">
                                                            <svg class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-900" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                                                                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12">
                                                                </path>
                                                            </svg>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <!-- content -->
                                                    <div>
                                                        <p><span>Elavarasan</span> |
                                                            <span>25-04-2022</span>
                                                        </p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div x-data="{ 'showModal': false }">
                                            <button @click="showModal = true" class="text-sm text-blue-600">
                                                Add Note</button>
                                            <div class="fixed inset-0 z-30 flex items-center justify-center overflow-auto bg-black bg-opacity-50" x-show="showModal" style="display: none;">
                                                <!-- Modal inner -->
                                                <div class="w-11/12 px-6 py-4 mx-auto text-left bg-white rounded shadow-lg md:max-w-md" @click.away="showModal = false" x-transition:enter="motion-safe:ease-out duration-300" x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 scale-90" x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 scale-100">
                                                    <!-- Title / Close-->
                                                    <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                                                        <div>
                                                            <p class="font-bold text-gray-900">
                                                                Add Note
                                                            </p>
                                                            <p class="text-sm font-semibold text-gray-600">
                                                                Elavarasan | 27-11-2023
                                                            </p>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <span @click="showModal = false">
                                                            <svg class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-900" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                                                                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12">
                                                                </path>
                                                            </svg>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <!-- content -->
                                                    <div class="w-full mt-4">
                                                        <div>
                                                            <label class="text-sm text-gray-600" for="">Add Notes</label>
                                                            <textarea rows="3" class="relative block w-full p-2 px-3 py-3 mt-1 text-gray-900 placeholder-gray-400 border border-gray-400 rounded shadow-sm appearance-none focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-600 focus:border-blue-600 focus:z-10" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="flex items-center gap-4 pt-6">
                                                            <button class="w-full p-2 font-semibold text-gray-900 bg-gray-100 rounded">Cancel</button>
                                                            <button class="w-full p-2 font-semibold text-white bg-blue-600 rounded">Save</button>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="p-4">
                                <div class="flex items-center gap-2">
                                    <span class="text-sm text-gray-900">
                                        10:00 AM
                                    </span>
                                    <div x-data="{ 'showModal': false }">
                                        <button @click="showModal = true" class="flex items-center text-blue-600"><span>
                                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="w-5 h-5 mr-1" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
                                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M11 5H6a2 2 0 00-2 2v11a2 2 0 002 2h11a2 2 0 002-2v-5m-1.414-9.414a2 2 0 112.828 2.828L11.828 15H9v-2.828l8.586-8.586z">
                                                    </path>
                                                </svg></span></button>
                                        <div class="fixed inset-0 z-30 flex items-center justify-center overflow-auto bg-black bg-opacity-50" x-show="showModal" style="display: none;">
                                            <!-- Modal inner -->
                                            <div class="w-11/12 px-6 py-4 mx-auto text-left bg-white rounded shadow-lg md:max-w-md" @click.away="showModal = false" x-transition:enter="motion-safe:ease-out duration-300" x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 scale-90" x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 scale-100">
                                                <!-- Title / Close-->
                                                <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                                                    <p class="font-bold text-gray-900">
                                                        Edit Time
                                                    </p>
                                                    <span @click="showModal = false">
                                                        <svg class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-900" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                                                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"></path>
                                                        </svg>
                                                    </span>
                                                </div>
                                                <!-- content -->
                                                <div class="w-full mt-4">
                                                    <div class="space-y-2 divide-y">
                                                        <div>
                                                            <label class="text-sm text-gray-600" for="">Time</label>
                                                            <div>
                                                                <input class="w-16 p-2 border border-gray-400 rounded-md" type="number">
                                                                <span class="font-bold">:</span>
                                                                <input class="w-16 p-2 border border-gray-400 rounded-md" type="number">
                                                                <span class="font-bold">:</span>
                                                                <select class="w-16 p-2 border border-gray-400 rounded-md">
                                                                    <option value="">AM</option>
                                                                    <option value="">PM</option>
                                                                </select>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div>
                                                            <label class="text-sm text-gray-600" for="">Reason</label>
                                                            <textarea rows="3" class="relative block w-full p-2 px-3 py-3 mt-1 text-gray-900 placeholder-gray-400 border border-gray-400 rounded shadow-sm appearance-none focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-600 focus:border-blue-600 focus:z-10" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="flex items-center justify-center w-full gap-4 pt-4">
                                                            <div class="w-1/2">
                                                                <button class="w-full p-2 font-semibold text-white bg-blue-600 rounded-md">Update</button>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            
                        </tr>
                        <!-- Add more rows as needed -->
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        <div
            class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center gap-4 pt-6 lg:flex-row lg:justify-between">
            <div class="flex items-center">
                <p class="pr-2 text-sm font-medium">Rows per page</p>
                <select id="jobtype" name="jobtype" autocomplete="jobtype"
                    class="block w-16 p-1 mt-1 text-sm bg-white border border-gray-400 rounded shadow-sm disabled:cursor-not-allowed focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-600 focus:border-blue-600 sm:text-base">
                    <option>10</option>
                    <option>25</option>
                    <option>50</option>
                    <option>100</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <nav class="relative z-0 inline-flex -space-x-px shadow-sm"
                    aria-label="Pagination">
                    <a href="#"
                        class="relative inline-flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-500 bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-l-md hover:bg-blue-100">
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                        <!-- Heroicon name: chevron-left -->
                        <svg class="w-5 h-5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                            viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                d="M12.707 5.293a1 1 0 010 1.414L9.414 10l3.293 3.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414l4-4a1 1 0 011.414 0z"
                                clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                        </svg>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#"
                        class="relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 hover:bg-blue-100">
                        1
                    </a>
                    <a href="#"
                        class="relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 hover:bg-blue-100">
                        2
                    </a>
                    <a href="#"
                        class="relative items-center hidden px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 md:inline-flex hover:bg-blue-100">
                        3
                    </a>
                    <a href="#"
                        class="relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 hover:bg-blue-100">
                        4
                    </a>
                    <a href="#"
                        class="relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 hover:bg-blue-100">
                        5
                    </a>
                    <a href="#"
                        class="relative inline-flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-500 bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-r-md hover:bg-blue-100">
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                        <!-- Heroicon name: chevron-right -->
                        <svg class="w-5 h-5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                            viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                d="M7.293 14.707a1 1 0 010-1.414L10.586 10 7.293 6.707a1 1 0 011.414-1.414l4 4a1 1 0 010 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0z"
                                clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                        </svg>
                    </a>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue comes from the fact that the *View log* and *Add note* modals are inside this element:

```html
<td class="sticky left-0 w-full p-4 bg-white whitespace-nowrap">
```

This element would be the [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_positioned_layout/Understanding_z-index/Stacking_context) for the modals. This means that relative to the navigation bar, pagination, etc, the effective `z-index` of the modals are `0`. This is because the `z-index` is **relative** to other elements inside the same stacking context, thus the `z-index: 30` of these modals is only relative to other elements inside the `<td>` element. Outside of this `<td>` element, the modals are effectively "grouped" with this `<td>` element's `z-index` of `0`.

The other modal triggered in the *Time* column works fine since its stacking context is the root of the document, `<html>`, thus its `z-index: 30` would apply in a meaningful way to other elements in the DOM.

You could consider increasing the `z-index` of the stacking context parent of the modals that don't work:

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@2.8.2/dist/alpine.min.js" defer></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <div class="relative">
      <div class="w-full overflow-x-scroll ">
        <table class="divide-y divide-gray-200 table-auto">
          <thead class="text-xs font-medium tracking-wider text-left text-white uppercase bg-blue-600 whitespace-nowrap">
            <tr class="py-4 divide-x">
              <th scope="col" class="sticky left-0 z-10 p-4 bg-blue-600">
                Name</th>
              <th scope="col" class="p-4">
                In Time</th>

            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody class="text-sm bg-white divide-y divide-gray-200 whitespace-nowrap">
            <tr>
              <td class="sticky left-0 w-full p-4 bg-white whitespace-nowrap z-30">
                <div class="flex items-center gap-2 w-max">
                  <img class="w-8 h-8 rounded-full" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/11.jpg" alt="">
                  <div>
                    <a href="" class="font-medium text-blue-600">John
                                                Doe</a>
                    <p class="text-xs text-gray-600">NA_1110</p>
                  </div>

                </div>
                <div>
                  <div class="flex items-center gap-4">
                    <div x-data="{ 'showModal': false }" @keydown.escape="showModal = false">
                      <button @click="showModal = true" class="text-sm text-blue-600">View Logs
                                            </button>

                      <div class="fixed inset-0 z-30 flex items-center justify-center overflow-auto bg-black bg-opacity-50" x-show="showModal" style="display: none;">
                        <!-- Modal inner -->
                        <div class="w-11/12 px-6 py-4 mx-auto text-left bg-white rounded shadow-lg md:max-w-md" @click.away="showModal = false" x-transition:enter="motion-safe:ease-out duration-300" x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 scale-90" x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 scale-100">
                          <!-- Title / Close-->
                          <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                            <p class="font-bold text-gray-900">
                              Attendance Log
                            </p>
                            <span @click="showModal = false">
                                                            <svg class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-900" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                                                                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12">
                                                                </path>
                                                            </svg>
                                                        </span>
                          </div>
                          <!-- content -->
                          <div>
                            <p><span>Elavarasan</span> |
                              <span>25-04-2022</span>
                            </p>
                          </div>

                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div x-data="{ 'showModal': false }">
                      <button @click="showModal = true" class="text-sm text-blue-600">
                                                Add Note</button>
                      <div class="fixed inset-0 z-30 flex items-center justify-center overflow-auto bg-black bg-opacity-50" x-show="showModal" style="display: none;">
                        <!-- Modal inner -->
                        <div class="w-11/12 px-6 py-4 mx-auto text-left bg-white rounded shadow-lg md:max-w-md" @click.away="showModal = false" x-transition:enter="motion-safe:ease-out duration-300" x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 scale-90" x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 scale-100">
                          <!-- Title / Close-->
                          <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                            <div>
                              <p class="font-bold text-gray-900">
                                Add Note
                              </p>
                              <p class="text-sm font-semibold text-gray-600">
                                Elavarasan | 27-11-2023
                              </p>
                            </div>

                            <span @click="showModal = false">
                                                            <svg class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-900" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                                                                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12">
                                                                </path>
                                                            </svg>
                                                        </span>
                          </div>
                          <!-- content -->
                          <div class="w-full mt-4">
                            <div>
                              <label class="text-sm text-gray-600" for="">Add Notes</label>
                              <textarea rows="3" class="relative block w-full p-2 px-3 py-3 mt-1 text-gray-900 placeholder-gray-400 border border-gray-400 rounded shadow-sm appearance-none focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-600 focus:border-blue-600 focus:z-10" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex items-center gap-4 pt-6">
                              <button class="w-full p-2 font-semibold text-gray-900 bg-gray-100 rounded">Cancel</button>
                              <button class="w-full p-2 font-semibold text-white bg-blue-600 rounded">Save</button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="p-4">
                <div class="flex items-center gap-2">
                  <span class="text-sm text-gray-900">
                                        10:00 AM
                                    </span>
                  <div x-data="{ 'showModal': false }">
                    <button @click="showModal = true" class="flex items-center text-blue-600"><span>
                                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="w-5 h-5 mr-1" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
                                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M11 5H6a2 2 0 00-2 2v11a2 2 0 002 2h11a2 2 0 002-2v-5m-1.414-9.414a2 2 0 112.828 2.828L11.828 15H9v-2.828l8.586-8.586z">
                                                    </path>
                                                </svg></span></button>
                    <div class="fixed inset-0 z-30 flex items-center justify-center overflow-auto bg-black bg-opacity-50" x-show="showModal" style="display: none;">
                      <!-- Modal inner -->
                      <div class="w-11/12 px-6 py-4 mx-auto text-left bg-white rounded shadow-lg md:max-w-md" @click.away="showModal = false" x-transition:enter="motion-safe:ease-out duration-300" x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 scale-90" x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 scale-100">
                        <!-- Title / Close-->
                        <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                          <p class="font-bold text-gray-900">
                            Edit Time
                          </p>
                          <span @click="showModal = false">
                                                        <svg class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-900" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                                                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"></path>
                                                        </svg>
                                                    </span>
                        </div>
                        <!-- content -->
                        <div class="w-full mt-4">
                          <div class="space-y-2 divide-y">
                            <div>
                              <label class="text-sm text-gray-600" for="">Time</label>
                              <div>
                                <input class="w-16 p-2 border border-gray-400 rounded-md" type="number">
                                <span class="font-bold">:</span>
                                <input class="w-16 p-2 border border-gray-400 rounded-md" type="number">
                                <span class="font-bold">:</span>
                                <select class="w-16 p-2 border border-gray-400 rounded-md">
                                  <option value="">AM</option>
                                  <option value="">PM</option>
                                </select>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                              <label class="text-sm text-gray-600" for="">Reason</label>
                              <textarea rows="3" class="relative block w-full p-2 px-3 py-3 mt-1 text-gray-900 placeholder-gray-400 border border-gray-400 rounded shadow-sm appearance-none focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-600 focus:border-blue-600 focus:z-10" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex items-center justify-center w-full gap-4 pt-4">
                              <div class="w-1/2">
                                <button class="w-full p-2 font-semibold text-white bg-blue-600 rounded-md">Update</button>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>

            </tr>
            <!-- Add more rows as needed -->
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center gap-4 pt-6 lg:flex-row lg:justify-between">
      <div class="flex items-center">
        <p class="pr-2 text-sm font-medium">Rows per page</p>
        <select id="jobtype" name="jobtype" autocomplete="jobtype" class="block w-16 p-1 mt-1 text-sm bg-white border border-gray-400 rounded shadow-sm disabled:cursor-not-allowed focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-600 focus:border-blue-600 sm:text-base">
          <option>10</option>
          <option>25</option>
          <option>50</option>
          <option>100</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div>
        <nav class="relative z-0 inline-flex -space-x-px shadow-sm" aria-label="Pagination">
          <a href="#" class="relative inline-flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-500 bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-l-md hover:bg-blue-100">
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            <!-- Heroicon name: chevron-left -->
            <svg class="w-5 h-5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                d="M12.707 5.293a1 1 0 010 1.414L9.414 10l3.293 3.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414l4-4a1 1 0 011.414 0z"
                                clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                        </svg>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 hover:bg-blue-100">
                        1
                    </a>
          <a href="#" class="relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 hover:bg-blue-100">
                        2
                    </a>
          <a href="#" class="relative items-center hidden px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 md:inline-flex hover:bg-blue-100">
                        3
                    </a>
          <a href="#" class="relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 hover:bg-blue-100">
                        4
                    </a>
          <a href="#" class="relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 hover:bg-blue-100">
                        5
                    </a>
          <a href="#" class="relative inline-flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-500 bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-r-md hover:bg-blue-100">
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            <!-- Heroicon name: chevron-right -->
            <svg class="w-5 h-5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                d="M7.293 14.707a1 1 0 010-1.414L10.586 10 7.293 6.707a1 1 0 011.414-1.414l4 4a1 1 0 010 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0z"
                                clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                        </svg>
          </a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The above code is working fine but If I add one more row, and If I click first row "view log" button means, it shows again second row as highlighted. How to fix this.

Comment: Have some JavaScript that ensures the `z-index` of the `<td>` where the *view log* is clicked is higher than other rows. You could also consider moving the modal HTML outside any stacking context parent via the [`x-teleport` directive](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/teleport#x-teleport) to avoid having to juggle `z-index`es.